# Send variable from one Jenkins pipeline to another one

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have one Jenkins pipeline (declarative) that produces unique variable.

And value of this variable is required for another pipeline (scripted).

How can I transfer it?

Answer (score 0):

I found simpler way, 
first job calls second with parameter:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    stages {
        stage('develop') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Triggering develop job.."'
                build (
                    job: 'ACP_DEVELOP',
                    parameters: [string(name: 'MY_VAR', value: my_var_val)]
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second job uses that parameter:

```
node
{
    properties([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'MY_VAR')
        ])
    ])

    print "DEBUG: MY_VAR = ${MY_VAR}"
}
```